# Dividing a data set almost equally among worker threads

Tags: c++, algorithm, logic

I have **n** number of elements and **p** number of threads. I am trying to divide the elements as equally as possible among the threads.

For example:

```
If n = 8 and p = 1, then [8]
If n = 8 and p = 2, then [4, 4]
If n = 8 and p = 3, then [2, 3, 3]
If n = 8 and p = 4, then [2, 2, 2, 2]
If n = 8 and p = 5, then [1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
If n = 8 and p = 6, then [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
If n = 8 and p = 7, then [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]
If n = 8 and p = 8, then [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

I cooked up a solution that almost works but not quite.

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int p = 5;
    const int SIZE = 8;
    int i = 0;
    int num = 0;

    std::vector<int> iter;

    if (p == 1)
        iter.push_back(SIZE);
    else
    {
        if (SIZE % p == 0)
        {
            num = SIZE / p;

            for (i = 0; i < p; ++i)
                iter.push_back(num);
        }
        else
        {
            num = (int)floor((float)SIZE / (float)p);

            for (i = 0; i < p - 1; ++i)
                iter.push_back(num);

            iter.push_back((SIZE - (num * (p - 1))));
        }
    }

    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < iter.size(); ++j)
        printf("[%d] = %d\n", j, (int)iter[j]);

    return 0;
}
```

Results produced with my solution:

```
If n = 8 and p = 1, then [8]
If n = 8 and p = 2, then [4, 4]
If n = 8 and p = 3, then [2, 2, 4]
If n = 8 and p = 4, then [2, 2, 2, 2]
If n = 8 and p = 5, then [1, 1, 1, 1, 4]
If n = 8 and p = 6, then [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3]
If n = 8 and p = 7, then [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]
If n = 8 and p = 8, then [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: what is your question? did you try to solve it with pen & paper?

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it. It should compile now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
std::vector<int> iter(p);
std::generate(iter.begin(), iter.end(), [&]()
{
    num += 1;
    return SIZE / p + (num <= SIZE % p ? 1 : 0);
});
```

The first line creates the required number of elements, and the second operator fills this vector with actual data. It is written without explicit loops to make code more expressive.

Comment: I thank you again for your help. Hopefully, nobody will delete this comment too.

Answer (score 5):

try to think about this. if you have less objects then threads then each thread will get one object. if you have more objects then threads (buckets) then think about how would you divide 100 tennis balls to 8 buckets.
you could take 1 ball at a time and put that in the next bucket, once you passed all buckets you start from first bucket, this will make sure that at most the difference between each bucket size will be 1.

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int p = 5;
    const int SIZE = 8;

    int p_size = SIZE > p ? p : SIZE;

    std::vector<int> iter(p_size);

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        iter[i%p_size] += 1;
    }


    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < iter.size(); ++j)
        printf("[%d] = %d\n", j, (int)iter[j]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see what you are saying. This is how Valery did it, albeit a lot more nicely. I would have used a regular loop instead (since I didn't know about std::generate()).

Comment: @FrankMaibaum i wanted to write some explanation to the code, and add it in a way that you can see the reflection of the explanation in the code.

Comment: I accepted Valery's post as the answer because he was the first to answer but your explanation/implementation is equally helpful and I thank you for it.

Answer (score 1):

This is less an answer to your specific question/problem, but more an alternative approach to your intended problem.

your solution is way to complicate... this code does the same, except the additional tasks are put into the front...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int p = 5;
    const int n = 8;

    // calculate number of tasks every thread have to do...
    int every = n / p;

    // calculate rest
    int rest = n % p;

    // initialize the vector with the number of tasks every thread have to do
    std::vector<int> lst(p, every);

    // split rest on the threads
    for(int i=0; i<rest; ++i)
        lst[i]++;

    // print out
    for(auto it : lst)
        std::cout << it << ",";

    return 0;
}
```

**The trick is integer truncation, there is no need for floating point arithmetics, as you probably see, the other answers also do...**

Comment: This implementation is also helpful. I am using C++ in the example code but in my actual project I am using standard C.

Comment: You should **NEVER** begin an answer with *"NOT AN ANSWER"*. (I don't see how this is not an answer, so I'm gonna leave it...)

Comment: @Zulan changed it :) I meant, it is not an answer because... see edit...